# Reading Hbase table values in Scala using Spark RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hbase, rdd

We have created a SparkRDD from a HBase table and now are wanting to access its elements. Here is what we have done:

1. Created RDD

```
val hBaseRDD = sc.newAPIHadoopRDD(conf, classOf[TableInputFormat], classOf[ImmutableBytesWritable], classOf[Result])
println("hbase RDD:")
hBaseRDD.collect().foreach(println)
```

2. The o/p of `hBaseRDD` is as follows:

```
(31 30 31,keyvalues={100/f1:id/1518081262631/Put/vlen=3/seqid=0, 
100/f1:name/1518081278652/Put/vlen=3/seqid=0})
(31 30 31,keyvalues={101/f1:id/1518081307150/Put/vlen=3/seqid=0, 
101/f1:name/1518081291946/Put/vlen=3/seqid=0})
```

3. The data in HBase table is:

```
 ROW                      COLUMN+CELL
 100                      column=f1:id, timestamp=1518081262631, value=100
 100                      column=f1:name, timestamp=1518081278652, value=abc
 101                      column=f1:id, timestamp=1518081307150, value=102
 101                      column=f1:name, timestamp=1518081291946, value=def
```

So the Spark RDD is returning length of actual data in HBase table but not the actual data itself. How to get the actual data from HBase table?

Answer (score 1):

When you collect the RDD you will have an `Array[Result]`

You can pass the `columnFamily` and `columnName` as parameters to the `Result.getValue` method to retrieve the value of each column:

```
hBaseRDD.collect().foreach(r => {
  val columnValue = r.getValue(Bytes.toBytes(columnFamily), Bytes.toBytes(columnName))
})
```

Comment: Please add more details about why this is the answer to the problem

Comment: added @JessBowers

Answer (score 0):

What you are doing is implicitly calling the `toString` method of `Result` (code is [here](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/rel/1.4.1/hbase-client/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Result.java#L813-L836)), which in turn calls the `toString` method of an implementation of `Cell` (most probably `KeyValue`, whose code is [here](https://github.com/apache/hbase/blob/master/hbase-common/src/main/java/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/KeyValue.java#L1128-L1135)).

As you see, the implementation of the `toString` method does not print the value, even though it's there.

HBase stores everything as raw bytes, so to pretty print them you have to call the `value` method on result and then decode it from `Array[Byte]` to what interests you.

```
def decodeValue(result: Result): Any = ???
hBaseRDD.map(result => s"$result -> ${decodeValue(result)}").foreach(println)
```

You'd have to implement `decodeValue` based on your schema.

To get some inspiration on how to decode your value, you can have a look at how they decode HBase values in the [source code of Eel](https://github.com/51zero/eel-sdk/blob/master/eel-hbase/src/main/scala/io/eels/component/hbase/HbasePublisher.scala#L71-L84).

Alternatively, you can directly print the values in their raw form by implementing the `decodeValue` function by calling the `value` method on the cell and then pretty printing the byte array.